# Build errors when iterating through QGraphicsItem items

Tags: c++, qt, for-loop, graphics

I have changed my class Item to inherit from QGraphicsItem, and suddenly getting problems...

```
class Item : public QGraphicsItem
{
    Item();
    QRectF boundingRect() const;
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
               QWidget *widget);
};

class CollectionView : public QGraphicsView
{
    Q_OBJECT    
public:
    CollectionView(QWidget *parent = 0);    
    QList<Item> *m_items;
};

class ShapeView : public QGraphicsView
{
    Q_OBJECT    
public:
    ShapeView(QWidget *parent = 0);
    CollectionView *collectionView;    
private:
    void doWork();
};

void ShapeView::doWork()
{
    outputView1->m_items->clear();
    foreach (Item item, collectionView->m_items)
   // for(int i = 0; i< collectionView->m_items->size(); i++)
    {
       // Item item = collectionView->m_items->at(i);    
       ...
    }
}
```

Either the for loop or the foreach, give me errors (were fine before inheriting from QGraphicsItem):

```
These errors if I use foreach:
'QList<Item>*' is not a class, struct, or union type
'class QForeachContainer<QList<Item>*>' has no member named 'i'
'class QForeachContainer<QList<Item>*>' has no member named 'e'
'class QForeachContainer<QList<Item>*>' has no member named 'i'
'class QForeachContainer<QList<Item>*>' has no member named 'i'
using invalid field 'QForeachContainer<T>::i'
request for member 'begin' in '((QForeachContainer<QList<Item>*>*)this)->QForeachContainer<QList<Item>*>::c', which is of non-class type 'QList<Item>* const'
using invalid field 'QForeachContainer<T>::e'
...
In copy constructor 'Item::Item(const Item&)':
'QGraphicsItem::QGraphicsItem(const QGraphicsItem&)' is private
within this context
In member function 'void ShapeView::doWork()':
synthesized method 'Item::Item(const Item&)' first required here
In member function 'Item& Item::operator=(const Item&)':
'QGraphicsItem& QGraphicsItem::operator=(const QGraphicsItem&)' is private

These errors if I use for loop: I only get:
In copy constructor 'Item::Item(const Item&)':
'QGraphicsItem::QGraphicsItem(const QGraphicsItem&)' is private
within this context
In member function 'void ShapeView::doWork()':
synthesized method 'Item::Item(const Item&)' first required here
In member function 'Item& Item::operator=(const Item&)':
'QGraphicsItem& QGraphicsItem::operator=(const QGraphicsItem&)' is private
```

What am I doing wrong, and what do these errors mean, and how can I fix them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the relevant part :

```
In copy constructor 'Item::Item(const Item&)':
'QGraphicsItem::QGraphicsItem(const QGraphicsItem&)' is private
within this context
```

You're inheriting from `QGraphicsItem` and you need to be copy-contructible, but [`QGraphicsItem` isn't copyable](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/57756e72adf2081137b97f0e689dd16c770d10b1:src/gui/graphicsview/qgraphicsitem.h#L471).

The copy constructor of `Item` is needed for the foreach in `ShapeView::doWork()`, so you'll have to either write that function differently and explicitely delete your copy constructor, or find a way to define a valid cctor. The same goes for `operator=`.

Comment: So what do I do ? It seems I have to inherit QGraphicsItem, so how do I create items based on other items, append to my list, or iterate through each ?

Comment: @Thalia either define a custom copy constructor and operator= that manually copy what you want, or make your Item non-copyable and use references/pointers/std::move to manipulate it. QGraphicsItem is not copyable, so you'll have to work around that.

Comment: Wyy do not you try to store and iterate pointers of your Item ? with:    QList< * Item> *m_items; and foreach (Item *item, collectionView->m_items)

Comment: Or even `foreach (Item&& item, collectionView->m_items)`.

Answer (score 0):

Effectively tux3 is right, you just need to redefine *cctor* and *operator=*. 
Nothing insurmontable, create your own class QGraphicsItem which inherit from 
QGraphicsItem.

file.h

```
 #include <QGraphicsItem>
    class MyGraphicsItem : public QGraphicsItem{
    MyGraphicsItem();//constructor
    MyGraphicsItem(const MyGraphicsItem& );//cctor
    MyGraphicsItem& operator=(const MyGraphicsItem& );//operator=
    }
```

file.cpp

```
  #include "file.h"
    //constructor
    MyGraphicsItem::MyGraphicsItem() : QGraphicsItem(){}
    //cctor
    MyGraphicsItem::MyGraphicsItem(const MyGraphicsItem& other){}
    //operator=
    MyGraphicsItem& MyGraphicsItem::operator=(const MyGraphicsItem& other){}
```

You don't need to write the body of *cctor* and *operator=*. The only purpose of this redefinition is to be able to handle *cctor* and *operator=* of a henceforth-*pseudo* class QGraphicsItem.

Don't be afraid of these signatures, for *cctor* you have choice between 4 possibilities :

```
MyClass( const MyClass& other );
MyClass( MyClass& other );
MyClass( volatile const MyClass& other );
MyClass( volatile MyClass& other );
```

for *operator=* you have choice between theses possibilities :

```
MyClass& operator=( const MyClass& rhs );
MyClass& operator=( MyClass& rhs );
MyClass& operator=( MyClass rhs );
const MyClass& operator=( const MyClass& rhs );
const MyClass& operator=( MyClass& rhs );
const MyClass& operator=( MyClass rhs );
MyClass operator=( const MyClass& rhs );
MyClass operator=( MyClass& rhs );
MyClass operator=( MyClass rhs );
```